# How to encode categorical variables for neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

In regression, you encode a categorical variable with n possible values using n-1 indicator variables. How about for neural networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do the same. Although people use $n$ instead of $n-1$ more often, which is probably just a matter of style.

Comment: Why? I'm just starting to learn neural networks, and so far I haven't read about anything that's the equivalent of the intercept in regression.

Comment: The intercept is often called bias in neural network texts.

Comment: Obviously I still have a good deal to learn about neural networks.

Comment: I don't think it is only *a matter of style*. See my answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding/329281#329281